# sending mail usingsprings with html content as text

Tags: spring, mail-sender

by using above code i send the mail, body with normal text. now i want to send the mail with html content as body any suggestions appriciate.

```
public void sendMail() {
                SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
                message.setFrom("xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
                message.setTo("xxxxxxx.yyyyyy@gmail.com");
                message.setSubject("Hi");
                message.setText("Welcome to FoodeeBuddee");
                javaMailSender.send(message)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create mail using velocity template refer to 24.3.2 Creating email content using a velocity template library for more [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html)  detail.